# How do I use child process spawn to run curl command?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to download a HAR file from saucelabs using the exec command, but I get this error when it downloads too much data:

RangeError [ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER]: stdout maxBuffer length exceeded

I've seen that child_process spawn is used instead for larger files, but I haven't managed to get it to work with all the parameters I am sending. Also I couldn't figure out how to return the downloaded data and store as a variable with spawn. Is anybody able to show me how to use spawn to get the data, and how to save that data into a variable for further processing.

Thanks

```
async getNetworkRequests (jobId) {
const harFile = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  exec(`curl -u "${process.env.SAUCE_USER}:${process.env.SAUCE_KEY}" --location --compressed --request GET 'https://api.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com/rest/v1/${process.env.SAUCE_USER}/jobs/${jobId}/assets/network.har'`, (error, stdout) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`Error message: ${error}`)
      reject(error)
    }
    resolve(stdout)
  })
})
return harFile
}
```

I've made some progress with spawn, but I am unable to get the data out of the stdout function:

```
async getNetworkRequests (jobId) {
const spawnProcess = spawn('/bin/sh', ['-c', `curl -u "${process.env.SAUCE_USER}:${process.env.SAUCE_KEY}" --location --compressed --request GET 'https://api.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com/rest/v1/${process.env.SAUCE_USER}/jobs/${jobId}/assets/network.har'`])

const output
spawnProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
  output = data.toString()
  })
console.log(output) // This returns undefined
}
```

Comment: You could make the request directly in the JS runtime instead of delegating to a `curl` subprocess, avoiding the additional complexity. Have you considered that approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
async getNetworkRequests (jobId) {
    // Wrap in a promise to export value from listeners
    const networkRequests = new Promise((resolve) => {
      // Spawn must be used as the buffer size too small if exec is used
      const spawnProcess = spawn('/bin/sh', ['-c', `curl -u "${process.env.SAUCE_USER}:${process.env.SAUCE_KEY}" --location --compressed --request GET 'https://api.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com/rest/v1/${process.env.SAUCE_USER}/jobs/${jobId}/assets/network.har'`])

      let combinedData = ''
      spawnProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
        // Keep adding data from the buffer
        combinedData += data
      })

      spawnProcess.stdout.on('end', () => {
        // On end event of request, parse and resolve the fully downloaded data
        resolve(JSON.parse(combinedData))
      })
    })
    return networkRequests
  }
```